# C# Obtaining a userPrincipalName on client side when connectted to Azure AD without a local domain controller

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I have Windows 10/11 endpoints being a part of Azure AD domain. The local DC (hybrid mode) is disabled.
I need to find out the userPrincipalName programmatically for every session/logged-in user.

Running **whoami.exe /upn** in the command line gives me proper UPN, like *user.user@domain.com*.

But the .NET code

```
string upn = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.UserPrincipalName;`
```

fails with:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'.                                                                                                                                                         at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)                       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.get_Current()

Is there any way to gigure out how **whoami** utility does the job? I cannot run any command liners from my code.

Comment: The property `UserPrincipal.Current.UserPrincipalName` returns the UPN just fine. What is your program's running identity - is the line of code running under some impersonation? The exception clearly states, `GroupPrincipal` is returned and it is not casting to `UserPrincipal` type.

Comment: No. It doesn't work as expected with pure Azure AD domain.
With LDAP and Azure Hybrid it does.

But I found this solution and it works:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946163/how-to-get-upn-for-authenticated-user-in-net-web-application-without-querying/35780463#35780463

Comment: Found this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946163/how-to-get-upn-for-authenticated-user-in-net-web-application-without-querying/35780463#35780463 The issue resolved.