# Lookup current users email address using EWS

Tags: exchangewebservices

In a desktop application I want to get the current user's email address to use Exchange Web Services auto discovery mechanism as [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn509511(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_SetURLusingAutoDiscover):

```
var svc = new ExchangeService()
                      {
                          UseDefaultCredentials = true
                      };
            svc.AutodiscoverUrl("user@company.com");
```

I know the current users `domain\username`; how do I get the email address before configuring EWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use something other then EWS to get that eg LDAP is generally the most common method eg see something like [Get UPN or email for logged in user in a .NET web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101938/get-upn-or-email-for-logged-in-user-in-a-net-web-application)

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Yeah I ended up looking up AD; similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1112225/269452)