# How to get current Azure Active Directory (AAD) user email from Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, azure, azure-active-directory

I need to be able to retrieve the current logged-on Azure AD user's email (technically a UPN) from Windows 10 via C#. I can get the following information:

```
WindowsIdentity currentIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

string userSid =
    currentIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(
        u => u.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.PrimarySid).Value;

string username = currentIdentity.Name; // This returns "AzureAD\\TestUser"
```

But what I really need is the email/UPN as below (test.user@testtenant.onmicrosoft.com):

[image: Windows 10 User Info]

I've looked through all properties of the `currentIdentity` object and can't see it anywhere, is this possible?

Comment: Please check this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4497032/13308381

Comment: @PamelaPeng I noticed that question shortly after posting, however it throws an `InvalidCastException` with the error message `Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the computer in question is Azure registered, it is not seen as on a domain (i.e. local network domain), therefore any operations involving connecting to a `PrincipalContext` will fail. The user's UPN is also not stored in the `WindowsIdentity` object, presumably for security?

It can be retrieved from the [GetUserNameEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/secext/nf-secext-getusernameexa) method in `secur32.dll` using something like the below:

```
public enum ExtendedFormat
{
    NameUnknown = 0,
    NameFullyQualifiedDN = 1,
    NameSamCompatible = 2,
    NameDisplay = 3,
    NameUniqueId = 6,
    NameCanonical = 7,
    NameUserPrincipal = 8,
    NameCanonicalEx = 9,
    NameServicePrincipal = 10,
    NameDnsDomain = 12,
}

[DllImport("secur32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int GetUserNameEx(int nameFormat, StringBuilder userName, ref int userNameSize);

public string GetCurrentUPN()
{
    StringBuilder userUPN = new StringBuilder(1024);
    int userUPNSize = userUPN.Capacity;

    if (GetUserNameEx((int)ExtendedFormat.NameUserPrincipal, userUPN, ref userUPNSize) != 0)
    {
        return userUPN.ToString();
    }

    return null;
}
```

This is obviously for the current user only, presumably to retrieve another user's UPN you'd need to contact the Azure AD tenant directly using the Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use
System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Upn

That will give you test.user@testtenant.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: I checked all claims on the returned object and UPN isn't in there, just the SID and some other identifiers which appear to be groups that the user belongs to.

Comment: Are you using the right namespace? I have used it in my code and can see also referred in MS docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimtypes.upn?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I checked through every claim that the returned object contained, along with the claim values, the UPN wasn't there at all. The `ClaimType` you are referring to is just a library of string constants to assist with cleaning up code, the actual value in the object's claims dictionary is `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn`. So no, this claim isn't in the `WindowsIdentity` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you can use [UserPrincipal.Current](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.current?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_UserPrincipal_Current) Property:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find current user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;

if(user != null)
{
   string loginName = user.SamAccountName; // or whatever you mean by "login name"
}
```

There is a similar issue about InvalidCastException: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31819930/13308381

Comment: `new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)` throws a `PrincipalServerDownException` with an inner `LdapException` with the error message `The LDAP server is unavailable.` and `UserPrincipal.Current` throws an `InvalidCastException` with the error message `Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'.`